# How to change the date in vba

Tags: excel, date, vba

I want to change the date on the basis of some condition. If the day is more than 15 the day should be 15 and if it is less than 15 the day should be 1.
The code for this is which i have written is :

```
date1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(k, 2).Value
tempArr = Split(date1, "/")
If (tempArr(2) < 15) Then
    reqdDate = tempArr(0) + "/" + tempArr(1) + "/01"
Else
    reqdDate = tempArr(0) + "/" + tempArr(1) + "/15"
End If
```

Its working fine for my system as the date format is yyyy/mm/dd. But for other systems its crashing as the system date is different. How to achieve this functionallity. I tried to change the format of the date

```
tempDate = Format(date1, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

But even this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
Dim d, reqdDate As Date
d = CDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(k, 2).Value)
If (Day(d) < 15) Then
    reqdDate = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
Else
    reqdDate = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 15)
End If
```

I recommend you to use Date-Type instead of strings. So you can use built in Functions.

After having your manipulated Date you can format it as you want to